# Need to send an Email Alert to Owners manager

Tags: workflow, configuration, email-alert

I need to create a workflow on the opportunity which will send an Email alert to owners manager.But I cannot see Owner manager in recipient Type.

I have tried to create a one Email field on Opportunity and using field update ,updated that email ID in the same workflow.but still, it is not running.I guess Email alert is firing first and then Field Update.
Please suggest if any solution.

Comment: Instead of updating the field with workflow, why you do not go for a formula field ?

Comment: Could you please explain in more details..

Comment: I am asking you to create a Email field of formula datatype and in that get the email id of the owner's manager. You need not create a workflow rule to update the email in the field. Formula would be somewhat like ownerId.Manager__r.Email

Comment: Is this possible without creating a new field .Is it possible using FLOWS?

Comment: I have never created flows but you a new field.can try them. Hopefully you may be able to send the email without

Answer (score 1):

See the 
[Workflow Execution Order](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=workflow_rules_considerations.htm&language=en) reference document

> The order in which individual actions and types of actions are
>   executed is not guaranteed. However, field update actions are executed
>   first, followed by other actions.

In this case, email field will be updated first and then email alert will be executed.

You can create custom Email Field with on Opportunity which will capture Owner's Manager Email. This email field will be updated using Workflow Field Update (Owner.Manager.Email)

You need to add one more action to send email alert in the same workflow rule.

You will be able to add this Email field in Recipient Type of a Email Alert.

Comment: thanks,I did the same thing,but I was not sure about the Execution order.but came to know that field update executed first then email update

Comment: This scenario worked for me. I am able to send an email after field update.

Comment: yes its working